# Very little Jdbc issue

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle9i

Can anyone please tell me to use which jdbc driver to connect with oracle 9.0.1.1?

i'm using jdk1.6.

i've used `classes12` and `ojdbc6` but they are causing errors.

Following is my code

Following bean's database related code is working in simple Java application but when i use it within JSF page it is giving Java null pointer exception error.
Thanks in advance.

Bean class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped     

public class Db implements Serializable{
    int eId;
    public int geteId() {
        return eId;
    }
    public void seteId(int eId) {
        this.eId = eId;
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:globldb3";
        String username = "scott";
        String password = "tiger";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        return conn;
      }
    public String addEmployee() throws Exception{
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            try {
                    int a = this.eId;
                    conn = getConnection();
                    String query = "INSERT INTO c(n) VALUES(?)";
                    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
                    pstmt.setInt(1,a); 
                    pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute insert statement
                    return "success";
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return "failure";
                 } finally {
                        pstmt.close();
                        conn.close();
                 }
     }     
}
```

Following is my JSF page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<body>
<h:form>
<p>Enter value  <h:inputText value="#{db.eId}"/> </p>
<p> <h:commandButton value="Add record" action="#{db.addEmployee}"/> </p>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following exception is comeing while using `ojdbc6.jar`.

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03120: two-task conversion routine: integer overflow

Following is stack trace of above exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03120: two-task conversion routine: integer overflow

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
at erpJavaFiles.Employee.addEmployee(Employee.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at       javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Tell us what the errors are, then.

Comment: ojdbc6.jar should be fine with Oracle 9 and JDK 6.  The code you're using to connect and stack trace of the exception would really be useful.  Like Jerry Maguire said, "Help me help you."

Comment: i've added the exception in the question kindly watch it.

Comment: What java code triggers the exception?  Show us the stack trace.

Comment: @sjaffman:wait let me add it in question

Comment: i've added my code and stack trace.kindly check it.

Comment: What is the value of a you are trying to insert?  What is the datatype of column c? I assume it's NUMBER; what are its precision and scale?

Comment: thanks very much to all of you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try ojdbc14.jar. it will work definetely.

Comment: How can you say "definitely" unless you know what exception he's getting?  Maybe his connection parameters are wrong.

Comment: How is this the correct answer?  If he was running ojdbc6.jar and got the exception why did ojdbc14.jar work?

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using classes12.jar; that's for JDK 1.2.  ojdbc6.jar is what you want; that's appropriate for JDK 6.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `a` and the data type of column `n` in table `c`. Ensure column `n` has a set length, i.e. NUMBER(10,0) vs just NUMBER.

I would try the query in SQL Developer too.  If you don't already have it you can get it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's Oracle bug 5671074 in some 9i versions that causes this exception when server and client have different "endianness".

Are you sure it's not your case?